# Pros and cons of using secureEvalJson over evalJson

Tags: jquery, json

When should I consider using

**secureEvalJSON**: `Converts from JSON to Javascript, but does so while checking to see if the source is actually JSON, and not with other Javascript statements thrown in.`

**evalJSON**: `Converts from JSON to Javascript, quickly, and is trivial.`

Can you show me an example where secureEvalJSON is beneficial over evalJSON??

What are the implications on the performance of using secureEvalJSON ?

More details about this API can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
{"test"  : "some_value",
 "test1" : "some_other_value",
 "test2" : alert("Hi, I'm code that is getting executed!")
}
```

the simple method will simply evaluate this using normal JavaScript (as if it were a plain object, which it is), and execute the `alert()` command in the process.

The secure method will (presumably) remove the `alert()`.

The secure method would be preferable e.g. when you're receiving code from an untrusted source, to prevent that source from running code in the current user's and page's context.